# Can we update a list using anonymous methods?

Tags: c#, delegates, anonymous-methods

I have a list (`MyList`) of objects...and I would like to update one property (`Priority`) of each item in that list.

Will the below code work for that ?

```
this.MyList.All(
    delegate(ItemViewModel itemObject)
    {   
        itemObject.Priority = priority++;
    }
)
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The extension method `All()` would return true/false depending on whether each item in the list met the criteria given in the delegate. Since the delegate doesn't return a Boolean, this shouldn't compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just use `foreach`?

```
foreach(ItemViewModel itemObject in MyList)
  itemObject.Priority = priority++;
```

If you really want to use a delegate you can use `ForEach()`:

```
MyList.ForEach(itemObject =>
{
    itemObject.Priority = priority++;
});
```

This is not advisable though since you introduce a side effect with `priority++`

Answer (score 1):

If it is a list, then you should use:

```
MyList.ForEach(i => i.Priority = priority++);
```

or the equivalent:

```
MyList.ForEach(delegate(ItemViewModel i) { i.Priority = priority++ });
```